# prevent SQL Server sproc from returning result set if select statement errors

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

if i have a stored procedure that handles errors in a catch statement is there a way to prevent an empty result set from returning if the select statement errors?

```
BEGIN TRY

select 1/0 as WHAT;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

SELECT 0 AS status_code;

END CATCH
```

looking to get back 1 result set regardless if it errors or if is succeeds (obviously this example will always error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
DECLARE @RESULT int

BEGIN TRY
  SELECT @RESULT =  1/0
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  SELECT @RESULT =  1
END CATCH

SELECT @RESULT
```

Comment: yah we were hoping to avoid using a temp table. it's either check if exists or do this. thank you for your answer. the real sproc actually returns multiple columns. up voted.

Comment: I kinda figured that. Yes you have to use temp table/variable for the approach above. Another approach - have 2 standalone selects like in your example and at receiving end always grab the last resultset. This will work universally whether there is error or not.

Comment: i like that idea. however we actually return record set and error set which is why this example may look odd to others. it works for the most part except if any selects error. marking as answer as i believe there is no setting or other trick to get it to work this way.